# Why am I getting malformed contract, in by C# code?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, code-contracts, microsoft-contracts

Visual Studio shows an error when I write this contract below.

`Error  20  Malformed contract section in method '....get_Page'`

Is the problem with the `if` block?

```
public int? Page
{
  get
  {
    int? result = Contract.Result<int?>();

    if (result != null)
        Contract.Ensures(result >= 0);

    return default(int?);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Lasse V. Karisen has posted in comments:

How about: `Contract.Ensures(result == null || result >= 0);` ?

Yes Karisen, I've tried this before and it compiles. But the question remains: isn't it possible to have `if`s when using contracts?

Another problem I'm having is clueless (mainly considering the example above works), involves the use of result also:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    Contract.Assert(item != null);
    Contract.Assert((item as IEntity).ID > 0);

    int result = Contract.Result<int>();
    Contract.Ensures(result >= -1);

    return default(int);
}
```

Comment: How about: Contract.Ensures(result == null || result >= 0); ?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't looked at code contracts for C# 4.0 yet, I'm still swamped with work in C# 3.0 and .NET 3.5. But, if the point of calling it a "contract" is that it is just that, then remember that criteria that stipulates when a contract is valid is written *in* the contract, not outside of it. You don't have a contract that says when that other contract is valid. So to me, this sounds like must be like this, you must write a contract that specifies when everything is peachy, and that contract must not be dependent on outside criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a guess. Perhaps it should be `Contract.Ensures(result.Value >= 0)`?

Comment: hum, result can be null actually.

Comment: Right, so perhaps `(result == null || result >= 0)`?

Comment: More generally, implication `if x then y` is `!x || y`, so here we have `!(result != null) || result >= 0` which simplifies to `result == null || result >= 0`.

Comment: More generally, implication 'if x then y' is 'x.Implies(y)', so here we have '(result != null).Implies(result >= 0)'

Answer (score 10):

The contract is malformed because all contract clauses MUST appear before any other code.

Comment: Yes, in C# all contracts go at the start. ( In eiffel Requires go at start, Ensures go at end. )

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an if, to do boolian manipulation instead use implies!

```
public int? Page
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures( (result!= null).Implies(result >= 0) );
        var result = ...

        ...


        return result;
    }
}
```

Also you should use Requires not assert when testing method arguments, and other preconditions.

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    Contract.Requires(item != null);
    Contract.Requires((item as IEntity).ID > 0);
...
```

Comment: Where exactly does Imply comes from? Ensures is a Void method and as such should not be capable of using any dotted notation afterward...

Comment: @bkqc `implies` is not called on `Ensures` it is a method of `bool` (or an extension method of bool).

Comment: right! I should learn to read :P I imagined an additional parenthesis lol. Is this in .Net Core? Because I can't find it anywhere in the .NET Framework. Could you tell me the dll/assembly it is in (F12 maybe)?

Answer (score 1):

All Ensures and Requires calls must be before all other statements in a method or property body, this includes simple assignments like you're using that help readability.

**Proper syntax**

```
public int? Page {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int?>() == null 
            || Contract.Result<int?>() >= 0); 

        return default(int?);
        }
    }
 }
```

This is *very ugly*, much uglier than normal `if (x || y) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()`.

**Special Attributes**

There is a somewhat roundabout way of getting around this.  `ContractAbbreviatorAttribute` and `ContractArgumentValidatorAttribute` are special attributes that the `ccrewrite` understands which make your life easier. (For lots of details see the [`System.Diagnostics.Contracts`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd287492%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace documentation on MSDN or the Code Contracts [manual](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf).)

***If using .NET 4 or older:***
These attributes are in the framework starting .NET 4.5, but for prior versions you can get a source file for them from the directory Code Contracts installs to. (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Languages\`) In that folder are `CSharp` and `VisualBasic` subfolders that have a `ContractExtensions.cs` (or .vb) file containing the required code.

**ContractAbbreviatorAttribute**
This attribute effectively lets you create contract macros.  With it, your page property could be written like this:

```
public int? Page {
    get {
        EnsuresNullOrPositive();
        return default(int?)
    }
}

[ContractAbbreviator]
static void EnsuresNullOrPositive(int? x) {
    Contract.Ensures(
        Contract.Result<int?>() == null ||                 
        Contract.Result<int?>() >= 0);
}
```

`EnsuresNullOrPositive` could also be kept in a static class and reused across your project, or made public and placed in a utility library.  You could also make it more general like the next example.

```
[ContractAbbreviator]
static void EnsuresNullOrPositive<Nullable<T>>(Nullable<T> obj) {
    Contract.Ensures(
        Contract.Result<Nullable<T>>() == null ||                 
        Contract.Result<Nullable<T>>() >= default(T));
}
```

For my own utility library, I have a static class named `Requires` and a static class named `Ensures`, each with many static methods decorated with `ContractAbbreviator`.  Here are some examples:

```
public static class Requires {

    [ContractAbbreviator] 
    public static void NotNull(object obj) {  
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);
    }

    [ContractAbbreviator]
    public static void NotNullOrEmpty(string str) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str));
    }

    [ContractAbbreviator]
    public static void NotNullOrEmpty(IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(sequence != null);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(sequence.Any());
    }
}

public static class Ensures {
    [ContractAbbreviator]
    public static void NotNull(){
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null);
    }
}
```

These can be used like this:

```
public List<SentMessage> EmailAllFriends(Person p) {
    Requires.NotNull(p); //check if object is null
    Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(p.EmailAddress); //check if string property is null or empty
    Requires.NotNullOrEmpty(p.Friends); //check if sequence property is null or empty
    Ensures.NotNull(); //result object will not be null

    //Do stuff
}
```

**ContractArgumentValidatorAttribute**
I haven't used this one outside of tutorials, but basically it lets you write package several `if (test) throw new ArgumentException()` calls in a single call that behaves like a call to `Contract.Requires`.  Since it only deals with argument validation, it wouldn't help with your post-condition example.

Answer (score -1):

Contract have conditional compilation flag on them.
In release more you code

```
if condition
    contract
return
```

becomes

```
if condition
   return
```

do you see the problem now?